# Can I configure PostgreSQL to reject SSL connections unless they are v1.2 or higher?

Tags: postgresql, tls

Can I configure PostgreSQL to reject TLS connections unless they are v1.2 or higher?

If so, can I get a doc link or instructions?

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: You can adapt the instructions of this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115422/how-is-possible-to-configure-tlsv1-1-protocol-for-ssl-connection-in-postgresql

Comment: First you should understand, that there is no such thing as, "SSL v1.2" you are thinking (SSL 1.0, SSL 2.0,SSL 3.0) and TLS (1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (draft) ).  *Based on the context you have used, I would image you only want to accept TLS 1.2+ connections, you should edit your question to reflect that fact.*

Comment: @Hennes I haven't tried anything yet, I'm not sure what I'm looking for - or whether it's actually possible. I have checked the docs and found https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-0-21.html which says PG supports negotation but nothing about configuring the allowed protocols.

Comment: The first step is to verify you have you configured your PostgreSQL installation to only accept SSL/TLS connections.  Once you have done that and have a valid certificate we can walk you through the steps to only accept specific SSL/TLS version connections

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I've already got my server set up like that. It's an RDS-managed PG running PostgreSQL 9.5.4

Answer (score 0):

RDS includes an option `rds.force_ssl`. Set this value to 1 and restart instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

Comment: Does that ensure that the connection is at least TLS 1.2?